# For loop in R starting from other value

Tags: r, loops

This has been bothering me for some time now. Imagine you have to/want to use a loop.

If you write a loop, but you want to start from the number 2, you'd use the following:

```
for (i in 2:length(variable1) { ... }
```

The problem arises when you try to assign values like such:

```
variable2 <- 1:length(variable1)
for (i in 2:length(variable1) {
    variable2[i] <- sample(variable1, 1)  # silly example; ignore it content-wise
}
```

Now, no matter if you would have a smaller vector initialized, it will often be problematic with the obtained variable2, since it has a "1" in the first position. What is the easiest way to deal with a for loop when you want to start from a higher number? And is there a better way than having to use `i <- i+i`, since we then have to also let it run from 1 to length(variable1) minus 1. Am I missing an easy solution?

While I am at it, what is the best way to predefine a variable before a `for` loop?
I usually use `variable2 <- 1:length(variable1)`, when I know variable2 should be a variable  with the length of `variable1`. Is this the fastest way to allocate memory?

EDIT: I kind of realized just now that it might be easiest to do:

```
variable2 <- 2:length(variable1)
for (i in 2:length(variable1) {
    variable2[i-1]
}
```

But I am still open for better suggestions.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this is not an `R` question -- it's a basic question for anyone learning how to use loops in programming.  You appear to be confusing array index with array values.  For example, try initializing this way:  `variable2<- vector(length=length(variable1))` , instead of filling it with values.

Comment: To answer your second point, just create an empty vector: `newvar <- vector(length(variable1))`. Optionally, specify a `mode` parameter to numeric, character, etc.

Comment: I would initialize variable2 with variable2 <- numeric(length(variable1)) if you want variable2 to ge have the same length as variable1. change out numeric() with whatever variable type applies

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am not "confusing" them, I just haven't found the way that works best. It all seems too much "effort".

Comment: @Dualinity why don't you give an example where it is *impossible* to avoid a `for` loop (referring to comment under Aaron's answer). Then there's a concrete problem to examine best practices of implementation. The way the question is currently phrased makes it too prone to conjecture and discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't hardcode the beginning index.

```
from <- 2
to <- length(variable) 
for (i in from:to) { 
  variable2[i - from + 1] <- sample(variable1, 1)
}
```

or, if you find that more expressive

```
offset <- 1
to <- length(variable) 
for(i in (offset + 1):to) { 
  variable2[i-offset] <- sample(variable1, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Themel's answer works great.

More generally you can use pretty much any sequence when iterating. so we could have

```
names <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Eve")
for(i in names) {
  print(i)
}
```

or

```
names <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Eve")
for(i in seq_along(names)) {
  print(names[i])
}
```

See `?seq_along` for a handy primer on that. `seq_along()` is nice because it is a little safer than specifying the array bounds yourself, should you want to iterate over the whole array.

You can iterate by an arbitrary sequence, e.g. `for(i in c(3, 5, 12, 47)) { # do stuff }`. If you get too tricky you'll trip yourself up, but bear in mind that you have that flexibility.

In this case the only thing I would change would be to avoid creating a variable for the end unless you're planning on having it be something other than the length of the vector. so:

```
from <- 2
for (i in from:length(variable)) { 
  variable2[i - from + 1] <- sample(variable1, 1)
}
```

There are also a number of ways around looping in R, and sometimes (though not always), exploring those is valuable.

Comment: I know, I use a lot of apply statements and what not. This is just something I have to really think about every time and haven't found the way that works best. Your last part really does seem like the solution, though really similar to themel's code. His "to" is obsolete in my opinion, but I guess setting the from is the way to go.

Comment: You can also use `for(i in seq_along(variable)[-1])` to start from the 2nd element in the vector, but that is probably too obfuscated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the usual R idiom would probably be to use `sapply` and let it handle the bookkeeping of filling up the result vector.  Something like this:

```
> sapply(2:5, function(x) {x*10})
[1] 20 30 40 50
```

Comment: We all know sometimes it is impossible to avoid a loop.

Comment: OK, well then let's have a question about one of them.  This question is about how to store the results when you're not iterating over `1:n`, and the most straightforward way to do that is with `sapply`, or to iterate over `seq_along` as Adam suggests.